# How to fix "Extract here" in context menu of Nautilus in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, nautilus, archive, extract

I have very strange problem with Nautilus on my fresh Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Gnome.

When I try to use "Extract here" context menu of Nautilus on some zip archive (700 Mb+ size), it creates folder named same as archive, also creates whole folders and sub-folders structure, that was in archive, creates all files, but - all files are of size 0 bytes.
On small zip archives "Extract here" worked as expected.

If I open same archive via Archive Manager and extract it that way - everything extracted properly.

If I extract archive from terminal via `unzip archive.zip` or `file-roller -h archive.zip` - everything extracted properly.

What I have tried:

- Removed and re-installed nautilus - did not helped
- Removed and re-installed zip and unzip - did not helped
- Selected `Files` as default tool for archives - does not help
- Installed `xarchiver` and selected it as default program for zip archives - did not helped
- Tried `bsdtar -xf archive.zip` - got errors `Unsupported ZIP compression method (bzip)`
- Checked for `bzip2` and for `p7zip-full` - both are installed
- Checked archive via `unzip -t archive.zip` - all files are OK

Also, digging for solution in Google, I found this:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/850
which is probably mine problem.

But for some other people it works just fine on same version of Ubuntu with Gnome and Nautilus.

On previous Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Unity "Extract Here" in Nautilus worked fine and extracted any archive of any size properly.

I'm really stuck and have no ideas how to fix this. As a backup solution I can use command line, but prefer to use GUI context menu if it possible.