# Use of 'Extract here' within Nautilus on zip files results in files of 0 bytes

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, zip

I have a file 'directory.zip' that I try to extract using Nautilus 'right click->extract here' (Ubuntu 20.040). This action generates 'directory' but it is empty (0 bytes).

If I open a terminal window and enter 'unzip directory.zip' I get 'directory' with all of the expected contents.

Seems to be related to a previous issue:

[How to fix "Extract here" in context menu of Nautilus in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236009/how-to-fix-extract-here-in-context-menu-of-nautilus-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

Thanks

Edit: Here is the output from running the command 'unzip -v directory.zip':

```
Archive:  directory.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 22:01 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 20:52 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/
    8476  Defl:X     2052  76% 2021-03-01 20:52 f7b98cc2  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/acqu
    8650  Defl:X     2219  74% 2021-03-01 20:53 8f3992a1  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/acqus
     642  Defl:X      434  32% 2021-03-01 20:53 97a9b544  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/audita.txt
  524288  Defl:X   253341  52% 2021-03-01 20:52 288bd18f  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/fid
    2389  Defl:X      657  73% 2021-03-01 20:51 89c3bf4e  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/format.temp
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 20:50 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/pdata/
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 20:53 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/pdata/1/
    1494  Defl:X      708  53% 2021-03-01 20:53 992108eb  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/pdata/1/auditp.txt
     396  Defl:X      264  33% 2021-03-01 20:53 d557f5e9  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/pdata/1/cycalc.log
    1122  Defl:X      471  58% 2021-03-01 20:53 ec133e89  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/pdata/1/filteredpeaks.txt
      89  Defl:X       65  27% 2021-03-01 20:53 84cc85d7  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/pdata/1/intrng
     480  Defl:X      327  32% 2021-03-01 20:53 cb1747cb  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/pdata/1/outd
    1349  Defl:X      404  70% 2021-03-01 20:53 c75d79bf  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/pdata/1/parm.txt
    3615  Defl:X     1295  64% 2021-03-01 20:53 0da827f0  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/pdata/1/peak.txt
    1478  Defl:X      484  67% 2021-03-01 20:53 9170e926  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/pdata/1/peaklist.xml
     175  Defl:X      134  23% 2021-03-01 20:53 29df3170  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/pdata/1/peakrng
    1088  Defl:X      849  22% 2021-03-01 20:53 0098678c  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/pdata/1/peaks
    2306  Defl:X     1017  56% 2021-03-01 20:53 5f9e77f4  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/pdata/1/proc
    2281  Defl:X      979  57% 2021-03-01 20:53 100e15ce  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/pdata/1/procs
      30  Stored       30   0% 2021-03-01 20:53 4fe7b435  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/pdata/1/samplename
     104  Defl:X      103   1% 2021-03-01 20:53 4c045c6d  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/pdata/1/title
   95660  Defl:X    91221   5% 2021-03-01 20:53 a39f2057  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/pdata/1/w6260-1H-zg30.pdf
    2042  Defl:X      724  65% 2021-03-01 20:51 7cb909b8  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/pulseprogram
     623  Defl:X      353  43% 2021-03-01 20:51 aec2d306  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/scon2
    3035  Defl:X      943  69% 2021-03-01 20:52 1ae19924  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/shimvalues
    4044  Defl:X     1542  62% 2020-12-29 18:43 468ced24  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/specpar
    5890  Defl:X     2022  66% 2020-11-12 10:23 6c8c844b  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/uxnmr.info
   25543  Defl:X     3479  86% 2020-11-12 10:23 bac0ea94  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/10/uxnmr.par
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 21:19 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/
    8546  Defl:X     2187  74% 2021-03-01 21:19 22b16264  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/acqu
    8726  Defl:X     2357  73% 2021-03-01 21:19 bdfa629a  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/acqus
     642  Defl:X      436  32% 2021-03-01 21:19 4f053907  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/audita.txt
    2088  Defl:X       99  95% 2018-03-13 00:46 3590b66d  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/cpdprg2
 2097152  Defl:X  1467701  30% 2021-03-01 21:19 a21e2e1d  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/fid
    3287  Defl:X      764  77% 2021-03-01 20:53 11b447ff  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/format.temp
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 20:53 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/pdata/
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 21:19 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/pdata/1/
     460  Defl:X      316  31% 2021-03-01 20:53 2251b54e  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/pdata/1/outd
    2300  Defl:X     1011  56% 2021-03-01 21:19 29ee99e0  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/pdata/1/proc
    2292  Defl:X      984  57% 2021-03-01 20:53 cf864404  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/pdata/1/procs
      30  Stored       30   0% 2021-03-01 21:19 4fe7b435  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/pdata/1/samplename
      98  Stored       98   0% 2021-03-01 21:19 44954be4  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/pdata/1/title
    4538  Defl:X     1218  73% 2021-03-01 20:53 1275f87f  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/pulseprogram
     623  Defl:X      354  43% 2021-03-01 20:53 47442459  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/scon2
    3035  Defl:X      938  69% 2021-03-01 21:19 9007384d  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/shimvalues
    4044  Defl:X     1542  62% 2020-12-29 18:43 468ced24  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/specpar
    5890  Defl:X     2022  66% 2020-11-12 10:23 6c8c844b  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/uxnmr.info
   25543  Defl:X     3479  86% 2020-11-12 10:23 bac0ea94  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/11/uxnmr.par
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 21:28 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/
    8598  Defl:X     2216  74% 2021-03-01 21:28 d3f90f13  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/acqu
    8784  Defl:X     2394  73% 2021-03-01 21:28 3d242f33  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/acqus
     642  Defl:X      435  32% 2021-03-01 21:28 b5a59408  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/audita.txt
    2088  Defl:X       99  95% 2018-03-13 00:46 3590b66d  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/cpdprg2
 1048576  Defl:X   704986  33% 2021-03-01 21:28 af57a517  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/fid
    4417  Defl:X      941  79% 2021-03-01 21:19 73adbff4  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/format.temp
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 21:19 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/pdata/
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 21:29 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/pdata/1/
     460  Defl:X      315  32% 2021-03-01 21:19 24f32afb  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/pdata/1/outd
    2290  Defl:X     1007  56% 2021-03-01 21:29 2b3eb615  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/pdata/1/proc
    2292  Defl:X      986  57% 2021-03-01 21:19 79533285  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/pdata/1/procs
      30  Stored       30   0% 2021-03-01 21:29 4fe7b435  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/pdata/1/samplename
      99  Stored       99   0% 2021-03-01 21:29 dc9883f0  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/pdata/1/title
    5392  Defl:X     1541  71% 2021-03-01 21:19 f3185687  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/pulseprogram
     623  Defl:X      353  43% 2021-03-01 21:19 e35f5168  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/scon2
    3035  Defl:X      942  69% 2021-03-01 21:28 dfa91d67  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/shimvalues
    4044  Defl:X     1542  62% 2020-12-29 18:43 468ced24  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/specpar
   26627  Defl:X     4052  85% 2018-03-13 00:51 dfb8e554  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/spnam5
    5890  Defl:X     2022  66% 2020-11-12 10:23 6c8c844b  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/uxnmr.info
   25543  Defl:X     3479  86% 2020-11-12 10:23 bac0ea94  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/12/uxnmr.par
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 21:29 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/
    8503  Defl:X     2066  76% 2021-03-01 21:29 a80bbfb8  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/acqu
     544  Defl:X      365  33% 2021-03-01 21:29 a1a6d520  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/acqu2
     543  Defl:X      364  33% 2021-03-01 21:50 2fb62dc6  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/acqu2s
    8673  Defl:X     2235  74% 2021-03-01 21:50 637657e7  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/acqus
     646  Defl:X      438  32% 2021-03-01 21:50 c110ac43  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/audita.txt
     512  Defl:X      286  44% 2018-03-13 00:46 160d3f4e  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/EA
    3596  Defl:X      804  78% 2021-03-01 21:29 776dae5f  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/format.temp
    1892  Defl:X      415  78% 2018-03-13 00:46 a538dbc7  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/gpnam1
    1892  Defl:X      415  78% 2018-03-13 00:46 a538dbc7  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/gpnam2
    1892  Defl:X      415  78% 2018-03-13 00:46 a538dbc7  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/gpnam3
      45  Defl:X       23  49% 2019-06-27 10:41 cd0720df  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/gradient_calib
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 21:29 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/pdata/
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 21:50 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/pdata/1/
    1519  Defl:X      692  54% 2021-03-01 21:29 371ecd4e  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/pdata/1/clevels
     462  Defl:X      315  32% 2021-03-01 21:29 420afa61  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/pdata/1/outd
    2317  Defl:X     1033  55% 2021-03-01 21:50 a2a759c1  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/pdata/1/proc
    2221  Defl:X      932  58% 2021-03-01 21:29 39eb9887  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/pdata/1/proc2
    2222  Defl:X      933  58% 2021-03-01 21:29 664316b3  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/pdata/1/proc2s
    2285  Defl:X      983  57% 2021-03-01 21:29 7daf8721  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/pdata/1/procs
      30  Stored       30   0% 2021-03-01 21:50 4fe7b435  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/pdata/1/samplename
      99  Stored       99   0% 2021-03-01 21:50 0eade6cd  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/pdata/1/title
    4101  Defl:X     1417  65% 2021-03-01 21:29 e1a174a4  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/pulseprogram
     623  Defl:X      353  43% 2021-03-01 21:29 d9836f3f  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/scon2
 4194304  Defl:X  1810642  57% 2021-03-01 21:50 b4154269  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/ser
    3035  Defl:X      940  69% 2021-03-01 21:29 8f373199  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/shimvalues
    4044  Defl:X     1542  62% 2020-12-29 18:43 468ced24  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/specpar
    5890  Defl:X     2022  66% 2020-11-12 10:23 6c8c844b  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/uxnmr.info
   25543  Defl:X     3479  86% 2020-11-12 10:23 bac0ea94  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/13/uxnmr.par
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 21:51 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/
    8780  Defl:X     2308  74% 2021-03-01 21:51 e9aa1c6f  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/acqu
     550  Defl:X      376  32% 2021-03-01 21:50 9a97f3ef  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/acqu2
     551  Defl:X      378  31% 2021-03-01 22:01 7ab72a0c  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/acqu2s
    8963  Defl:X     2491  72% 2021-03-01 22:01 8bf33383  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/acqus
     648  Defl:X      437  33% 2021-03-01 22:01 6e34d500  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/audita.txt
     435  Defl:X      144  67% 2018-03-13 00:46 77696921  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/cpdprg2
     512  Defl:X      286  44% 2018-03-13 00:46 160d3f4e  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/EA
    7504  Defl:X     1269  83% 2021-03-01 21:50 c3ebd9a8  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/format.temp
    1892  Defl:X      415  78% 2018-03-13 00:46 a538dbc7  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/gpnam1
    1892  Defl:X      415  78% 2018-03-13 00:46 a538dbc7  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/gpnam2
      45  Defl:X       23  49% 2019-06-27 10:41 cd0720df  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/gradient_calib
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 21:50 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/pdata/
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 22:01 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/pdata/1/
    2041  Defl:X      790  61% 2021-03-01 21:50 b5783004  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/pdata/1/clevels
     462  Defl:X      316  32% 2021-03-01 21:50 dcda048e  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/pdata/1/outd
    2285  Defl:X     1011  56% 2021-03-01 22:01 3e32e46e  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/pdata/1/proc
    2193  Defl:X      914  58% 2021-03-01 21:50 0c980915  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/pdata/1/proc2
    2229  Defl:X      939  58% 2021-03-01 21:50 06dbe6cf  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/pdata/1/proc2s
    2285  Defl:X      983  57% 2021-03-01 21:50 ad2e77ed  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/pdata/1/procs
      30  Stored       30   0% 2021-03-01 22:01 4fe7b435  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/pdata/1/samplename
      99  Stored       99   0% 2021-03-01 22:01 c128ef91  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/pdata/1/title
    9173  Defl:X     2651  71% 2021-03-01 21:50 9165eaa5  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/pulseprogram
     623  Defl:X      354  43% 2021-03-01 21:50 f334f683  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/scon2
 3407872  Defl:X  1272225  63% 2021-03-01 22:01 01391fd1  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/ser
    3035  Defl:X      939  69% 2021-03-01 21:51 c5a09a39  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/shimvalues
    4044  Defl:X     1542  62% 2020-12-29 18:43 468ced24  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/specpar
   52780  Defl:X    12761  76% 2018-03-13 00:51 acb31894  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/spnam14
   52840  Defl:X    13025  75% 2018-03-13 00:51 c7d158ef  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/spnam18
   26761  Defl:X     5161  81% 2018-03-13 00:51 9a979393  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/spnam3
   52780  Defl:X    12761  76% 2018-03-13 00:51 acb31894  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/spnam31
    5890  Defl:X     2022  66% 2020-11-12 10:23 6c8c844b  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/uxnmr.info
   25543  Defl:X     3479  86% 2020-11-12 10:23 bac0ea94  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/14/uxnmr.par
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 22:02 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/
    8824  Defl:X     2314  74% 2021-03-01 22:02 f7a341b2  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/acqu
     548  Defl:X      373  32% 2021-03-01 22:01 af428f83  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/acqu2
     550  Defl:X      378  31% 2021-03-01 22:41 0413f3a9  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/acqu2s
    9013  Defl:X     2503  72% 2021-03-01 22:41 bb71586d  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/acqus
     646  Defl:X      438  32% 2021-03-01 22:41 2f713360  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/audita.txt
     512  Defl:X      286  44% 2018-03-13 00:46 160d3f4e  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/EA
    5662  Defl:X     1073  81% 2021-03-01 22:01 be700d7b  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/format.temp
    1892  Defl:X      415  78% 2018-03-13 00:46 a538dbc7  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/gpnam1
    1892  Defl:X      415  78% 2018-03-13 00:46 a538dbc7  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/gpnam3
    1892  Defl:X      415  78% 2018-03-13 00:46 a538dbc7  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/gpnam4
    1892  Defl:X      415  78% 2018-03-13 00:46 a538dbc7  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/gpnam5
    1892  Defl:X      415  78% 2018-03-13 00:46 a538dbc7  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/gpnam6
      45  Defl:X       23  49% 2019-06-27 10:41 cd0720df  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/gradient_calib
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 22:01 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/pdata/
       0  Stored        0   0% 2021-03-01 22:41 00000000  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/pdata/1/
    1521  Defl:X      694  54% 2021-03-01 22:01 9efcef43  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/pdata/1/clevels
     462  Defl:X      316  32% 2021-03-01 22:01 91a37b31  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/pdata/1/outd
    2288  Defl:X     1012  56% 2021-03-01 22:41 8bb59686  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/pdata/1/proc
    2192  Defl:X      916  58% 2021-03-01 22:01 990ae9b2  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/pdata/1/proc2
    2229  Defl:X      939  58% 2021-03-01 22:01 e9bb5a83  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/pdata/1/proc2s
    2285  Defl:X      983  57% 2021-03-01 22:01 1484ae43  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/pdata/1/procs
      30  Stored       30   0% 2021-03-01 22:41 4fe7b435  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/pdata/1/samplename
      99  Stored       99   0% 2021-03-01 22:41 fae8bf6d  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/pdata/1/title
    8337  Defl:X     2239  73% 2021-03-01 22:01 52bb246e  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/pulseprogram
     623  Defl:X      352  44% 2021-03-01 22:01 3df114fe  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/scon2
 8388608  Defl:X  3124244  63% 2021-03-01 22:41 b2392ac7  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/ser
    3035  Defl:X      940  69% 2021-03-01 22:02 b56de19d  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/shimvalues
    4044  Defl:X     1542  62% 2020-12-29 18:43 468ced24  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/specpar
   26627  Defl:X     4052  85% 2018-03-13 00:51 dfb8e554  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/spnam7
    5890  Defl:X     2022  66% 2020-11-12 10:23 6c8c844b  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/uxnmr.info
   25543  Defl:X     3479  86% 2020-11-12 10:23 bac0ea94  zips/GB-MBG33_CPOPEG-DTT-HPLC-FRAC2-w6260/15/uxnmr.par
--------          -------  ---                            -------
20487256          8906196  57%                            165 files
```

Comment: What happens if you double-click the file (open with archive manager). Do you see the contens there? Btw; I cannot reproduce the issue...

Comment: I can navigate around the zipped directory with no problems using archive manager. The contents are all there. Very strange - this action used to work fine and has only become an issue in the past 10 days or so.

Comment: All using the GUI: Select directory->open with archive manager->'Extract'->'Extract' also results in files showing correctly after unzipping. It is only when I click 'Extract here' that this issue arises

Comment: Strange thing. Try command `file-roller --extract-here directory.zip`. This should be the same as what `nautilus` does

Comment: 'file-roller --extract-here directory.zip' provides me with 'zips/directory'; all of the files are extracted as expected. Note that 'Right click->Extract here' provides me with 'directory' (not 'zips/directory') with a file size of 0 bytes.

Comment: Same problem, but not with all zip files, regardless of file size, some files work, others don't extract. With double-click all files are visible, and clicking on "Extract" button, all files are created. Only right-click -> "Extract here" don't create all files. And if I add files to zip file with drag-drop over the zip, only files added are extracted

Comment: I get the same behaviour when I try to "extract here" a password protected 7z archive. When I open it with an archive manager I get no issues tho (it correctly asks for my password).